# How to make overlay and section disappear when i click outside with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make this:

When the user clicks both the closeBtn and the window, the overlay effect and the popup disappear.

I could not figure out why so far only the first section and the overlay disappear and when I go I'll try with the second section, only the overlay disappears.

In total there are five avatar divs and five iframe sections. When you click on an avatar, the corresponding section and the overlay should appear and when you click on the closeBtn or outside, both should disappear.

```js
$(".avatar").click(function() {
  $('.iframe').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('open');
  $('.overlay').addClass('open');
});

$('.iframe_close').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.iframe').removeClass('open');
  $('.overlay').removeClass('open');
});

var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
var iframeAvatar = document.querySelector('.iframe');

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (event.target === overlay) {
    overlay.className += 'overlay';
    iframeAvatar += 'iframe';
  }
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.avatar {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iframe {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.iframe.open {
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
}

.iframe_avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.iframe_close {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="img/mauricio.jpg" alt="">
  <span class="avatar-info"><p><strong>Maurício Munhoz</strong><br/>
    Diretor/Consultor Técnico</p>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="img/alexandre.jpeg" alt="">
  <span class="avatar-info"><p><strong>Alexandre Lúcio da Silva</strong><br/>
    Consultor Lean Manufacturing</p>
  </span>
</div>
<section class="iframe">
  <div class="iframe_avatar">
    <img src="img/mauricio.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="iframe_info">
    <span class="iframe_close">&times;</span>
    <p><strong>Maurício Munhoz</strong><br/> Diretor/Consultor Técnico</p>
    <p>Fundador e Diretor da Munhoz Consultoria, Maurício vem trabalhando como Consultor Técnico desde 2003, liderando projetos de certificação de mais de 20 organizações de diferentes segmentos industriais e de prestação de serviço. Atua desde 2008 como
      Auditor de terceira parte para a maior certificadora mundial de sistemas e produtos: Bureau Veritas Certification. Engenheiro Mecânico com 40 anos de experiência profissional, tendo atuado em todos os processos principais e de apoio: suprimentos,
      produção, engenharia, qualidade, assistência técnica e manutenção.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="iframe">
  <div class="iframe_avatar">
    <img src="img/alexandre.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="iframe_info">
    <span class="iframe_close">&times;</span>
    <p><strong>Alexandre Lúcio da Silva</strong><br/> Consultor Técnico</p>
    <p>Formado em Engenharia Industrial pela Universidade Braz Cubas de Moji das Cruzes - SP. Antes de fundar a Munhoz Consultoria, Maurício atuou como Engenheiro e Supervisor da Qualidade na Valeo Sistemas Automotivos Ltda, com a coordenação de equipes
      de técnicos e engenheiros, planejamento de atividades, tratamento de não conformidades, planejamento e gerenciamento de custos e investimentos da área da qualidade, negociação em compras e aprovação de projetos. </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you adjust your js code like following this should work:

```
$(".avatar").click(function() {
    $('.iframe').eq($(".avatar").index($(this))).toggleClass('open');
    $('.overlay').addClass('open');
});

$('.iframe_close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.iframe').removeClass('open');
    $('.overlay').removeClass('open');
});

$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
    $('.iframe').removeClass('open');
    $('.overlay').removeClass('open');
});
```

And no need following part:

```
/*var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
 var iframeAvatar = document.querySelector('.iframe');

 window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (event.target === overlay) {
   overlay.className += 'overlay';
   iframeAvatar += 'iframe';
  }
 })*/
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much! So simple! how did I not think of that before!? hahaha